# Need to get h1 tag text

Tags: selenium-ide

**I need to take text between the  tag using selenium IDE.

```
    <div class="product-name">
    <h1>**This text i need to take**</h1>
     </div>
```

i use below code but i should be sent wrong value

```
    <table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1">
    <thead>
 <tr><td rowspan="1" colspan="3">New Test</td></tr>
 </thead><tbody>
    <tr>
<td>store</td>
<td>css=div.product-name&gt;h1</td>
<td>pp</td>
         </tr>
       <tr>
<td>clickAndWait</td>
<td>//a[contains(text(),'This text i need to take')]</td>
<td></td>
      </tr>
   <tr>
<td>echo</td>
<td>${pp}</td>
<td></td>
   </tr>

   </tbody></table>
      </body>
     </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<td>store</td>
<td>xpath=//h1</td>
<td>pp</td>
```

Also:

```
<td>clickAndWait</td>
<td>//a[contains(text(),'This text i need to take')]</td>
<td></td>
```

does not exist in the code snippet you posted! If this is the problem, please update your original post.